# Changes to LaTeX kernel in June 2022 affect use of \MakeUppercase in chapter titles

Tags: chapters, latex3

I follow the tips in [Koma-Script HowTo_ChapterWithLines](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_ChapterWithLines/) to reformat the chapter heading.
With the June 2022 update of the LaTeX kernel this no longer works and goes into an infinite loop.
I am running `LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5 L3 programming layer <2022-07-04>`
The error message after interrupting the compilation is:

```
chapter 1.
^C! Interruption.
\tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF ...w \prg_do_nothing: #1
                                                   }{\exp_after:wN {\token_t...
l.35 \chapter{Introduction}
```

A MWE demonstrating the problem is:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{microtype}

% Do not put a dot after Section/Chapter, nor in the figure caption.
\KOMAoptions{numbers=noendperiod}
% Write Chapter 1 at beginning of each chapter
\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=true,appendixprefix=true}

\makeatletter
% Code from https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_ChapterWithLines/
\renewcommand*{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\nobreak
  }{}%
  \@hangfrom{\textsl{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}{\textsl{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\nobreak
  }{}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \raggedleft
    \textls{\MakeUppercase{#2}}%
    \rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\nobreak
    \raggedchapter
    \textls{#3}%
    \rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\nobreak
  }{#2#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

Here is an introduction.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry about that, it's a miracle it worked before, but this restores an `edef`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{microtype}

% Do not put a dot after Section/Chapter, nor in the figure caption.
\KOMAoptions{numbers=noendperiod}
% Write Chapter 1 at beginning of each chapter
\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix=true,appendixprefix=true}

\makeatletter
% Code from https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_ChapterWithLines/
\renewcommand*{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
\protected@edef\tmp@chaphead{#2}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\nobreak
  }{}%
  \@hangfrom{\textsl{\MakeUppercase{\tmp@chaphead}}}{\textsl{\MakeUppercase{#3}}}%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\nobreak
  }{}%
}
\renewcommand*{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}[3]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \raggedleft
\protected@edef\tmp@chaphead{#2}%
    \textls{\MakeUppercase{\tmp@chaphead}}%
    \rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\nobreak
    \raggedchapter
    \textls{#3}%
    \rule[.3\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1pt}\par\nobreak
  }{#2#3}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}


Here is an introduction.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\robustify\usekomafont
\AddToNoCaseChangeList{\usekomafont}`  seems to work too, but it is a miracle that it worked before ;-)

Comment: The first option works very well thanks. I have one more question. Is it straightforward to have a different font size for "Chapter" and the chapter number?

Comment: @Ian_B probably but I don't know the documented koma interfaces that well, better to ask a new question about that and someone will answer.

Comment: I managed to fix this problem by redefining `\chapterformat` using
```
 \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
   \MakeUppercase{\Large\chapapp}\enskip\Huge\thechapter\autodot
}
```